# Non cluster indexing with combination or on single entity for multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, index, nonclustered-index

I am new to db design I also read concepts of non cluster indexing and know about the combined non cluster indexing but in my scenario I am having user table with multiple search on column

```
table column as follows 
 userName
 fatherName
 empId
 cardNumber
and so on. (above all 4 no one column is PK)
```

I am having around 50 millions records over here due to large data search take huge time due to that I am thinking to create indexes in table but these all 4 searches are optional means possible user can fill all four or may be one or two of them but I was confused if I make all four separate index and one for all 4 then it might be creating issue on performance of while entering/inserting the data I created even a single index for all 4 column in combined but while I am searching with only card number then it takes huge time shall I created all four separate indexes would this work in combined search of  empId and cardNumber

If I created separated once then what about combined searches If I create combinations then indices are 15 which obviously not a good way for insertion...
lot of confusion I have can anyone help me thanks in advance

Comment: its about 50 million rows, please remeber to ose number that are known

Comment: Best bet is to index just all four, and add one extra column to some of them. `userName` with any of the others is not likely to be queried so that doesn't need extra columns etc. Look at what users are querying

Comment: Can you provide example queries that are having performance issues, the exact table DDL and your current indexes?